# 32bit and 64bit ODBC Drivers playing nice with PHP

Tags: php, apache, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I am running PHP on a 64bit windows 2008 server. I have both ODBC 32bit and 64bit installed and I attempt to do this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);
```

The 32bit ODBC install has the driver `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` and the 64bit version has the `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` which is what I need but PHP says it cant find it and I am assuming PHP is only referencing the 32bit ODBC driver.

Why is this the case? Is it as simple as PHP/Apache being a 32 bit install?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure 32bit odbc settings through admin snap in only by calling it from command line or browse to it in Explorer in folder

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

By default in Administration Tools in Control Panel you will start only 64bit version which PHP will not use.

Now tell me which did you use to configure your odbc connection?

Comment: When I go to administrative tools, the 64bit box pops up. I have to manually go to the 32bit version. So you are saying because PHP is a 32 bit install it will be using the 32 bit driver?

Comment: Yes, it uses 32bit driver version

Comment: Just a quick follow up, if only a 64bit ODBC driver is installed, PHP will use that right?

Comment: I think no. I have had same issue while ago with ruby, since it was 32bit script implementation it uses 32bit driver only. It is not aware that OS is 64bit, reason is that Windows (and other OSs too) runs such processes in isolated space and creates wrapper around it. That wrapper will provide only 32bit system components, like 32bit com+ in windows OS.

Comment: The path you provided for the 32-bit odbc administrator is incorrect. Counterintuitively, that is the 64-bit one. The 32-bit one is located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused as to what I need to do when I get to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe window.  Do I need to change some settings to get PHP to look in the right place for the drivers?

Comment: execute that program and configure connection to your database and give it a name, then use such name in your php script